# How to modify value in column typeorm

Tags: sql, typeorm

I have 2 tables contractPoint and contractPointHistory 
ContractPointHistory

[image]

ContractPoint

[image]

I would like to get contractPoint where `point` will be subtracted by `pointChange`. For example: ContractPoint -> `id: 3, point: 5`
ContractPointHistory has `contractPointId: 3 and pointChange: -5`. So after manipulating point in contractPoint should be `0`

 I wrote this code, but it works just for `getRawMany()`, not for `getMany()`

```
const contractPoints = await getRepository(ContractPoint).createQueryBuilder('contractPoint')
      .addSelect('"contractPoint".point + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(cpHistory.point_change) FROM contract_point_history AS cpHistory WHERE cpHistory.contract_point_id = contractPoint.id), 0) AS points')
      .andWhere('EXTRACT(YEAR FROM contractPoint.validFrom) = :year', { year })
      .andWhere('contractPoint.contractId = :contractId', { contractId })
      .orderBy('contractPoint.grantedAt', OrderByDirection.Desc)
      .getMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `getMany` can be used to select all attributes of an entity. However, if one wants to select some specific attributes of an entity then one needs to use `getRawMany`.

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder) -

> There are two types of results you can get using select query builder:
> **entities** or **raw results**. Most of the time, you need to select real
> entities from your database, for example, users. For this purpose, you
> use `getOne` and `getMany`. But sometimes you need to select some specific
> data, let's say the sum of all user photos. This data is not an
> entity, it's called raw data. To get raw data, you use `getRawOne` and
> `getRawMany`

From this, we can conclude that the query which you want to generate can not be made using `getMany` method.